# If ActiveRecord::Base#create is deprecated in 3.2.13, how am I using it still?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running 3.2.13 and following the standard "railstutorial.org" I've run into a question. I'm still getting the hang of switching from a C++/Java programming mindset, and trying to understand normal calling conventions.

I can use my class (`User < ActiveRecord::Base`) like:

```
User.create(email: "email", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
```

The [doc for the method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) indicates that it is deprecated. I also see no reference to a `def create` in my ActiveRecord gem source.

Since the call is not using a Hash, what is the name of that kind of invocation? Is it the same if the arguments were wrapped in curly brackets?

Comment: From what I understand it was just moved from `ActiveRecord::Base` to `ActiveResource::Base`. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/create/class

And that is still a `Hash` but with the new Ruby 1.9 syntax.

Comment: I was thinking that too... but I can't find the "line" from ActiveRecord to ActiveResource. My basic understand has me failing to uncover an ActiveResource "import" from ActiveRecord.

Comment: ActiveResource is a totally different thing!!! ActiveResource is to interact with REST services but the API is similar to ActiveRecord. It was removed from rails and now you must add it to your gems to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two questions are being asked here.

#### First question: method deprecation

Changes were made in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ceb33f84933639d3b61aac62e5e71fd087ab65ed).

The `create` method was [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ceb33f84933639d3b61aac62e5e71fd087ab65ed#L4L529) from `ActiveRecord::Base` and [inserted](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ceb33f84933639d3b61aac62e5e71fd087ab65ed#L11R40) into a separate module called `ActiveRecord::Persistence`.

Regarding what APIDock told you... the method was "deprecated **or moved**." If you look halfway down the list of suggestions, you will see `ActiveRecord::Persistence#create`. This is where the method moved to.

Note that `ActiveRecord::Persistence#create` is used internally. When calling `create` on an ActiveRecord **model** (not object) in your application code, you are invoking [`ActiveRecord::Relation#create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/create).

`ActiveResource::Base#create` was introduced in Rails 2.0 and is unrelated to ActiveRecord.

#### Second question: hash as arguments

Examining the [source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create) for `ActiveRecord::Relation#create` shows the following:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 85
def create(*args, &block)
  scoping { @klass.create(*args, &block) }
end
```

See the splat argument `*args`? This tells Ruby to pass all remaining arguments into `args`, no matter how many there are. Ruby/Rails' ducktyping magic sees a bunch of key-value pairs and assumes it to be a hash.

Rails is a bit loose with requiring curly brackets for hashes in arguments, just as it is loose about wrapping all arguments in parentheses. Generally, Rails will infer a hash when you pass in a series of key-value pairs. Sometimes this causes trouble when passing in multiple hashes, like in a complex `form_for` method.

If you have erratic behavior with curly brackets absent, insert them. Clearly defining hashes will allow you to ensure proper behavior.

Read more about Ruby splats [here](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

Answer (score 1):

"Deprecated" doesn't mean "no longer available". It means it *will* be no longer available soon.

Comment: I do know what "deprecated" means... that's why I mentioned that I was not able to find the definition in my installed gem's source. :D The doc says "This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v3.1.0) is shown here.".

Comment: +1. Deprecation means something is discontinued and will be removed in the future, so you shouldn't implement it, or should replace it if already implemented.

Comment: Deprecation definition and meaning understood!!! Now where is the replacement for ActiveRecord::Base#create ? :)